# Bevel making the vertices cursed to dodecahedron

Tags: vertices, bevel

[image: Here the image]

So, when I add bevel feature to dodecahedron and set it to vertices, this happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely have to remove these inner edges:

[image]

Select one, then select menu, select similar length:

[image]

Finally, <kbd>X</kbd> and choose 'dissolve edges'.

---

But if I can advice, doing it bevelling the vertices may lead to this if you shade smooth (or autosmooth):

[image]

So I propose to make it another way:

With the edges removed as above,

Inset individuals: select all then <kbd>I</kbd> and make sure 'individual' is checked.

Select all and add crease.

Back to object mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> to add subdivisions.

Shade smooth.

(you can play with the crease to harden more or less)

[image]